# How to properly use two contextual filter for taxonomy

Tags: 7, views

this is my case:

- I have a content type called "norm".
- Each norm has two fields with taxonomy terms: "issuing institution" and "norm type".
- Each taxonomy field has its own vocabulary.

I'm making a View that will:

- Filter all the "norms" that are issued by "institution A" or "institution B".
- Has two contextual filters. One for "insitution", second for "norm type".
- If the first parameter is not given, just show a summary with the instituions (in this case, just two institutions). [This is working]
- Then, if the second parameter is not given, just show a summary with the "norm type". I mean this will be a list of norm types that has been issued by institution %1 (first parameter).

But, the last is not working. It shows again the instituion.

How can I do this kind of thing?

Comment: Try reading about http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the views checks the first parameter and the first parameter overrides the second parameter. In your case, if you rearrange parameters so that parameter 2 comes before parameter 1, you will see this time views working with parameter 2 and not with parameter 1.

You can fix this behavior by creating two separate pages in views and each page will override the behavior of the other by selecting For:"This page(override)" option.

In the first page add the two contextual filters(parameter 1 and parameter 2). While adding the contextual filters you have to select For:"This page(override)".

In the second page of the views, add the two contextual parameters, this time add parameter 2 before parameter 1. In this case also, while adding the parameters you have to select For:"This page(override)".

Good luck!